# Vue.js list filtering - no results fallback

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a list using Vue.js which can be filtered by the user when they type in a search term. What I would like it to do is show a message such as "no results" when the term they enter isn't in the list.

This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the SEO term you wish to find" v-model="search" />
<ul class="ls-none">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in filteredList" :key="index">
        <h4>{{item.glossary_term}}</h4>
        <div v-html="item.glossary_definition"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    search: '',
    glossary: <?php echo $json; ?>

  },
  computed: {
    filteredList: function() {
      var self=this;
      function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.glossary_term < b.glossary_term)
          return -1;
        if (a.glossary_term > b.glossary_term)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }
      this.glossary.sort(compare);
      return this.glossary.filter(function(item){
          return item.glossary_term.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/\s/g, '').indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/\s/g, ''))>=0;
      });
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

I tried using a combination of v-for and v-if but not sure exactly what I need to check for on the if statement.

Something like:

```
<div v-if="/*glossary item is there in the list*/"></div>
```

Comment: Did you try to check the length of the `filteredList`? If it is 0 then the term is not in the list.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.protype.filter` method returns an empty array if no elements pass the test. So you can set up `v-if` on the `<li>` to check if tthe `filteredList` is empty or not.

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the SEO term you wish to find" v-model="search" />
<ul class="ls-none">
    <li v-if="filteredList.length " v-for="(item, index) in filteredList" :key="index">
        <h4>{{item.glossary_term}}</h4>
        <div v-html="item.glossary_definition"></div>
    </li>
    //if empty display no results text
    <li v-else>No results...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, great so I would do something like: v-if filteredList.length > 0?

Comment: Sweet, fixed it! Thanks

Comment: @RyanMc no need `> 0` , you can just check `filteredList.length`. If 0 it will be coerced to false and the `else` condition will kick in